# HTTP: to send big data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

ASP.NET Core MVC 2

I need to send big raw data (the `byte[]`). My `POST`-request contains the `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` header.

This is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RawBinaryDataManual()
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
    return StatusCode((int) HttpStatusCode.OK);
  }
}
```

It works fine when I post 22Mb file, but I get the `Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException'` error if I try to send the 38Mb file.

How can I fix this problem?

**UPD**
Thanks to [phuzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592958/phuzi) - he wrote [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core) in the comments which helped to me to solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe posting the stack trace would also help?

Comment: My *Call Stack* window is empty after exception occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @phuzi Thank you! The `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` or `[RequestSizeLimit(1024 * 1024 *1024)] // not more than 1Gb` attributes solved this problem.

Comment: Though keep in mind you are loading the whole file into memory at once here. Better have enough RAM available :) Otherwise, you will need to use Streams.