# Why do I get a 404 trying to post a large file to a Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient, kestrel-http-server

I am very new to file transfer between `HttpClient` and a Web API, so please excuse any ignorance and guesswork in my code. I have been trying to post a file created with `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` to my web API now for about a day, and always I get a 404 response. If I post with an empty stream, the API action method is invoked, so I know the 404 is due to content and not the URI.

This method is in the client WPF application that attempts to post the file:

```
public async Task PostDirAsync(string localDirPath, string serverDir)
{
    var sourcePath = Path.Combine("Temp", Guid.NewGuid() + ".zip");
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(localDirPath, sourcePath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
    StreamContent streamContent;
    using (var fs = File.Open(sourcePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        await fs.CopyToAsync(outStream);
        outStream.Position = 0;
        streamContent = new StreamContent(outStream);
    }
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    var resp = await _client.PostAsync("api/File/PostDir?serverPath={WebUtility.UrlEncode(serverDir)}", streamContent);
}
```

And this is the action method in the Web API that receives the post, but only if I don't do the `outStream.Position = 0;` before attempting to post:

```
[HttpPost("PostDir")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostDir(string serverPath)
{           
    var zipName = Path.Combine(_config["QuickDrive:TempDir"], Guid.NewGuid() + ".zip");
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(zipName))
    {
        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        await ms.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

The action method is invoked and runs without error with an empty stream, but is pretty useless as it writes an empty file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I expect that when you call `ms.CopyToAsync(fileStream);`, you're at the end of the `ms` stream. You likely need something like `ms.Position = 0;` before that line.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Nope, still an empty file.

Comment: Well there's a similar situation where you set the `StreamContent` to a stream that might already be at the end. You should be able to see positions and lengths in the debugger on these streams, if that helps. Look at the `Request.Body` stream too.

Comment: @KirkLarkin It looks like you're right. When I do an `outStream.Posiition = 0` before `streamContent = new StreamContent(outStream);`, I now get my old friend the 404 response. It seems `streamContent` was empty before, but now the it has content and the web api objects to the type of that content.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your first problem was that the `Stream` instances involved in the file copying were not being reset using `Stream.Position = 0`. I know you've made these changes already, but I just want to emphasise that this is a two-part solution.

So, the second part:

In your example code, you've added the `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` annotation in order to bypass the default ASP.NET Core 2.0+ Kestrel request limits. However, there's also a limit that's imposed by IIS, which is 30MB by default. When this size limit is exceeded, IIS itself generates a 404 response, which is what you're seeing.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43250595/2630078) explains how to change this limit using a custom `Web.config` (included below for completeness):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 1 GB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

As somewhat of a side note:

Unless you have a specific reason to do so, you can avoid the use of `MemoryStream` in your code and just pass `fs` directly into `new StreamContent(...)`. You can do something similar with the `Request.Body` stream and copy that directly into the output `FileStream`. This would end up with:

```cs
public async Task PostDirAsync(string localDirPath, string serverDir)
{
    var sourcePath = Path.Combine("Temp", Guid.NewGuid() + ".zip");
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(localDirPath, sourcePath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);

    var streamContent = new StreamContent(File.Open(sourcePath, FileMode.Open));
    streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    var resp = await _client.PostAsync("api/File/PostDir?serverPath={WebUtility.UrlEncode(serverDir)}", streamContent);
}
```

And with:

```cs
[HttpPost("PostDir")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostDir(string serverPath)
{           
    var zipName = Path.Combine(_config["QuickDrive:TempDir"], Guid.NewGuid() + ".zip");
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(zipName))
        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(fileStream );
    return Ok();
}
```