# How to increase the upload file size limit in ASP.NET core 2.1 project?

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to upload the files more than 30 MB in ASP.NET core 2.1. While adding the configuration in the startup.cs (MaxRequestBodySize, MultipartHeadersLengthLimit) file or controller (RequestSizeLimit) or program.cs file, none of these are not working for me. I have attached my sample below. Can you please suggest any other way to achieve this?
Sample link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6b11b27fbc4f714fcdba1195ea25d68920190404102752/2c1f24

I have tried suggested solution from this link [Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core) but issue is not resolved.

Comment: Put your project codes on a Github repo instead.

Comment: *Don't* post your project code on a Github repo or anywhere else. Post the *relevant* code in the question. `I have tried suggested solution from this link` which ones? What is the *actual* problem, actual error?