# Asp.Net Core -> Refuse requests bigger than pre-defined amount?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to refuse a request with a body (content-length header probably) larger than a predefined amount?

Comment: If you are using IIS you can set maxAllowedContentLength.

Comment: nope, not using IIS...

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestsizelimitattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.0) could help?

Comment: "refuse a request" -- do you mean "refuse" like a firewall dropping the connection, or do you mean "refuse" like send back a 500 status code or similar

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566617/5751404) for different host service .

Comment: Are you using nginx?