# ASP.NET Core 3.1 | Argument model always null with large form data in controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

As I am developing a web application in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I am passing large form data using ajax into my controller and it is always null.

If I decrease the amount of data, then it works fine, but with large amounts of data, it's always null.

Below links already tried

[Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

[New default 30 MB (~28.6 MiB) max request body size limit](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267)

This is my Ajax call

```
publicObject.PostRequest = function (url, data, onSuccess, onError, _withoutLoader) {
            $.ajax({
                url: _url,
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'RequestVerificationToken': $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                cache: false,
                data: _data,
                success: function (_data) {
                    //CFD.Loader.hide();
                    _onSuccess(_data);
                },
                error: function (result, textStatus, _xhr) {
                    CFD.Loader.hide();
                    if (_result.status == 401) {
                        CFD.User.GetLoginModal('loginsection');
                    }
                    _onError(_result);
                }
            });
        };
```

Here is my controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
[RequestSizeLimit( int.MaxValue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts(VMProductFilter model)
{
    List<VMProduct> resultModel = null;

    try
    {
        resultModel = await GetAllProducts(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Log();
    }

    return PartialView("_ProductGrid", resultModel);
}
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Try using Gzip to compress your form data and uncompress it on the server.

Comment: How large was your data? I tried 50MB multipart form data, and it just worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

Configure request limits in the Startup.cs.

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...

        services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            //x.ValueLengthLimit = Settings.ValueLenLimit;
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Settings.MulBodyLenLimit;
            //x.MemoryBufferThreshold = Settings.MemoryBufferThreshold;
        });

        //...
    }
```

If IIS is used, it also needs to be configured in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741822" /><!-- 1GB-->
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set FormOptions in your StartUp class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Set limits for form options, to accept big data
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
    {
        x.BufferBody = false;
        x.KeyLengthLimit = 2048; // 2 KiB
        x.ValueLengthLimit = 4194304; // 32 MiB
        x.ValueCountLimit = 2048;// 1024
        x.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = 32; // 16
        x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = 32768; // 16384
        x.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = 256; // 128
        x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 134217728; // 128 MiB
    });

    ...

} // End of the ConfigureServices method
```