# View is passing null values to controller on submit when sends a lot of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, form-submit

I am creating an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I have a view that receives a model that has a `List<>` property.

This is what the view looks like:

```
@model InfoUpdateModel

<form action="@Url.Action("TakeoverCoverage", "Participant")" id="formTakeoverCoverage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off">

@for (int index = 0; index < Model.AvailablePlans.AvailablePlansClient.Count; index++)
{
      <input type="text"  asp-for="@Model.AvailablePlans.AvailablePlansClient[index].CoverageRate" class="form-control" value=" @Model.AvailablePlans.AvailablePlansClient[index].CoverageRate" />
       <input id="LastDayPreCobra@(index)" class="form-control datepicker group-date-picker" value=@Model.AvailablePlans.AvailablePlansClient[index].LastDayPreCobra asp-for="@Model.AvailablePlans.AvailablePlansClient[index].LastDayPreCobra">
    ..
    ..//others fields to input data
    ..
}
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         FormTakeoverCoverage();
     });

     function FormTakeoverCoverage() {
         $('#formTakeoverCoverage').submit(function (event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             if ($(this).valid()) {
                 var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));
                 $.ajax({
                     url: this.action,
                     type: this.method,
                     data: formdata,
                     processData: false,
                     contentType: false,
                     dataType: "json",
                     headers: {
                         "RequestVerificationToken":
                             $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                     },
                     beforeSend: function () {
                     },
                     success: function (result) {
                         }
                         else {
                             }
                     },
                     complete: function () {
                     }
                 }
                 );
             }
             return false;
         });
     }
</script>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("TakeoverCoverage")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ClientWebError(IsPartial = true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> TakeoverCoverage(InfoUpdateModel model)
{}
```

The view renders all the model's data, 1, 10 or 100 rows.

When I submit the view with less than 63 records, the controller gets the model with the data. But when the model has more then 63 records, the controller receives `null` in the model.

I have to show 220 in total and breaks in 63 records. I tried returning the first 64 or latest 64 and have the same problem. It is not a data issue.

I do not know if there is a memory issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I followed what says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295714/asp-net-core-3-1-argument-model-always-null-with-large-form-data-in-controller)

and add this

```
  builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
    x.ValueCountLimit = 4096;
});
```

To my `program.cs`