# How can I upload a 2.3gb file in .net 5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-5

I have a task to allow uploads from an internal application that's built in .net5 razor pages of greater than 2gb per file.  I have changed all the settings in the web.config and on server to allow these files to upload but still am greeted with a 400 error when trying.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>

<requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3147001541" />
    </requestFiltering>
```

I am using the following to upload the files

```
var path = Path.Combine(targetFileName, UploadedFile.FileName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await UploadedFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
```

then after that it just saves the location in the DB of where that file was copied.

Comment: `maxRequestLength` is in kB. 20480kB is 20MB. That is considerably smaller than 2GB.

Comment: This answer is for .NET Core, but since .NET 5 is its successor, it might apply to your problem as well: [Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38698350/87698)

Answer (score 0):

`system.web` settings are only used by ASP.NET (not Core). In ASP.NET Core you change the limit for your action by adding the `RequestSizeLimitAttribute` or `DisableRequestSizeLimitAttribute`. Additionally you will likely need to increase form data limit by adding `RequestFormLimitsAttribute`.

MVC:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(3147001541)]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 3147001541)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    // ...
}
```

Razor Pages:

```
@attribute [RequestSizeLimit(3147001541)]
@attribute [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 3147001541)]
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#multipart-body-length-limit) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core) for details.

Comment: Forgot to add I"m using Razor Pages. THis doesn't seem to work in razor pages