# Asp.Net MVC Upload a Video File Size Greater than 2MB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I has a one API Solution(Target Framework 4.0) and one MVC Solution(Target Framework 4.5.1) of job portal. In profile summery I need to upload a video but the problem I faced , I can not upload a video file which size is greater than 2MB. So, I search on internet and find a solution is that change the **web.config** on Api Solutions with this as mension below,

```
Web.config
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 <httpRuntime executionTimeout="108000" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
</system.web>
 <system.webServer>
    <!-- maxAllowedContentLength = 2GB (the value is in Bytes) -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

after apply this same problem occurred "Failed!The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

Here my Controller Code on MVC solutions
**CandidateController**

```
 #region UPDATE CANDIDATE PROFILE SUMMERY
        [HttpPost]
        public string UpdateProfileSummery(string info)
        {
            string Res = "";
            string Token = "";string FileName="";
            ResultInfo<string> ResultInfo = new Models.ResultInfo<string>();
            CandidateProfileSummery ProfInfo = new CandidateProfileSummery();
            try
            {
                if (info != "" && info != null)
                {                    
                    ProfInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CandidateProfileSummery>(info);
                    
                    //ProfInfo.Gender = ProfInfo.NamePrefix == "Mr." ? "male" : "female";
                    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //  Get all files from Request object  
                        HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                        if (User.Identity.Name != "" && User.Identity.Name != null)
                        {
                            string[] arr = User.Identity.Name.Split('|');
                            Token = arr[0];
                            ProfInfo.ID = Convert.ToInt64(arr[3]);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                        {
                            HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                            int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
                            FileName = file.FileName;
                            if (file.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".mp4")|| file.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".mov") || file.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".wmv") || file.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".avi") || file.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".flv") || file.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".mkv") || file.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".3gp"))
                            {
                                ProfInfo.VideoType = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                                if (ProfInfo.VideoType != ".mp4" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".MP4" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".MOV" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".mov" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".WAV" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".wmv" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".AVI" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".avi" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".FLV" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".flv" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".MKV" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".mkv" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".3GP" && ProfInfo.VideoType != ".3gp")
                                {
                                    Res = "Failed! File type should be video file.";
                                }

                                else
                                {                                    
                                    MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                                    file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                                    byte[] fileData = target.ToArray();
                                    ProfInfo.VD = fileData;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ProfInfo.FileType = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                                if (ProfInfo.FileType != ".png" && ProfInfo.FileType != ".jpeg" && ProfInfo.FileType != ".jpg" && ProfInfo.FileType != ".gif")
                                {
                                    Res = "Failed! File type should be jpeg/jpg or png.";
                                }
                               
                                 else
                                {
                                   
                                    MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                                    file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                                    byte[] fileData = target.ToArray();
                                    ProfInfo.DP = fileData;
                                }
                            }

                            
                            

                        }

                        string fname;
                        if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                        {
                            string[] testfiles = FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                            fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //In this section I got error when file size > 2MB
                            string JsonRes = WebService.Postfile(ApiUrl + "Jobseeker/updateJbsProfileSummery?Token=" + Token, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProfInfo));
                            ResultInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultInfo<string>>(JsonRes);
                            if (ResultInfo.ErrorCode == 200)
                            {
                                Res = "Success! " + ResultInfo.Info;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Res = ResultInfo.Info;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (User.Identity.Name != "" && User.Identity.Name != null)
                        {
                            string[] arr = User.Identity.Name.Split('|');
                            Token = arr[0];
                            ProfInfo.ID = Convert.ToInt64(arr[3]);
                        }

                        string JsonRes = WebService.Postfile(ApiUrl + "Jobseeker/updateJbsProfileSummery?Token=" + Token, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProfInfo));
                        ResultInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultInfo<string>>(JsonRes);
                        if (ResultInfo.ErrorCode == 200)
                        {
                            Res = "Success! " + ResultInfo.Info;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Res = "Failed! Information is not provided.";
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Res = "Failed!" + ex.Message;
            }
            return Res;
        }
        #endregion
```

Is it any problem on Api solution webconfig file "maxRequestLength" not supported on target framework 4.0
If anyone solve my problem, Thank You In Advanced

Answer (score 0):

add this config

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; //50MB
});
```

for more way visit this link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: But That's for Asp.net Core . There is no startup class in my mvc or api project

Comment: I has Global.asax file