# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR when using TempData in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core

When I don't use TempData, the page works fine, but when I use it I get the following error.

```
This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://localhost:44332/Home/UploadFile might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Here's the code of the controller

```
TempData["Response"] = responseString;
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Did you check length of the `responseString`?

Comment: You are correct, my responseString was too long. By the way what needs to be used to pass huge data?

Comment: The `TempData` uses [HTTP cookies or session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#state-management). You an try few ways to increment a request size limit: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45927665/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45927665/6630084)

Comment: you inlighted me thankl you. i got the same error nowadays for my project i built in 2017. it was web form. when i see your question i noticed that it's MVC. In MVC, TempData is exactly equal to the public variable in Web Form. So, it's amazing. Thank you.