# Video Upload more than 100MB throwing 404 error

Tags: asp.net-core, cloudflare, kestrel, ocelot

I am trying to enable the functionality of video upload up to 190MB. I am using .Net core with Ocelot Gateway. I am able to successfully upload videos up to 190MB locally. But when I try to upload with Ocelot Gateway(on test environment), I am getting a 404 error. We have Cloudflare on the test environment and that is enabled for up to 200MB video upload.

I have applied following changes:
In web.config of web project and gateway project

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="220200960" />
</system.web>

<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="220200960" />
```

On API Endpoint:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(220200960)]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 220200960)]
```

In web startup.cs

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
  options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
  options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; 
});
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
  x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
  x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; 
  x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

I am getting the following warning in Gateway:

> Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
> requestId: 0HMFB1RBKJ31C:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnmappableRequestError
> Message: Error when parsing incoming request, exception:
> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
> 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream
> destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Ocelot.Request.Mapper.RequestMapper.ToByteArray(Stream stream)
> at Ocelot.Request.Mapper.RequestMapper.MapContent(HttpRequest request)
> at Ocelot.Request.Mapper.RequestMapper.Map(HttpRequest request, DownstreamRoute downstreamRoute) errors found in
> ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request
> path:/v1/File/CreateFile, request method: POST

Nothing above helped me. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @ZahidMustafa Tried all the steps but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stack trace, it mentions as out of memory exception, which could point towards an issue copying such a large file into memory (if your server has low free memory). Have you verified your server has > 200 MB of free memory at the time of upload?

I also found this post, which sounds like a somewhat similar issue with Ocelot - https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/884

Could try setting MaxRequestBodySize to null to see what happens? Although they were not receiving 'out of memory' exception, so could be unrelated.