# Azure request faling for .net application

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights

Currently, I am working on .net project deployed on Azure. It is related to car insurance sending electronic slips to users/brokers/carriers. One of our customers has faced error in generating e-slips today and by looking at azure application insights we found 10 request failed with 400 response . Type:Azure blob. But it does not provide details of this error.

What code does- We have various carriers/brokeres registered to our insurance company website. So brokers can create further users who wish to get insured and issue pink slips/insurance slips to them and users can download that in their apple wallet. Users can add as many insured vehicles as they want. So the error is coming now when broker hit send eslip to user post/api/integration/elsip. This requests fails

I checked for the API that failed was post/api/integration/eslip. I am new to Azure, so if anyone can give me insight as to how to check what caused the error. The application is running fine though.

Comment: Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **400 error** might be caused by a URL that is **incorrectly typed** or contains **unrecognizable** characters. An **incorrect or expired cookie** could also be the source of the problem.

I hope in your case you attempt to **upload a file** that is **very huge**. You may receive a **400 error** if the server is programmed with a file size limit. **Make sure to increase your file size limit**.

Still, you are facing any issues, please refer to [To Fix 400 Bad Request](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request)

#### References:

- [Increase upload file size in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)
- [Set Max Request Length in .net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Set-MaxRequestLength-in-ASPNet-Core.aspx)