# How to increase upload file size limit with ServiceStack on ASP.Net Core 5+

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicestack

I need to upload large files using a ServiceStack Service, hosted on an AspNetCore 5.0 application.  Attempting to usethe AspNetMvc attribute doesn't work.

```
[Route("/api/tehformz", "POST")]
public class BigFileUploadRequest {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string DeviceTypeId { get; set; }
}

[RequestSizeLimit(300 * 1024 * 1024)]

public ResponseStatus Post(BigFileUploadRequest request) {
...
}
```

I've tried adding a MiddleWare handler like below.  It is executed, but not honored.

```
private async Task FallbackMiddlewareHandler(HttpContext httpContext, Func<Task> next)
{
            httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = null;
            await next();
}
```

It might be worth noting I am posting the file as form data, and it works fine for smaller uploads.

How do I update my middle ware or decorate my service call so I can upload files larger than AspNetCore's ~30MiB limit?

[image]

Comment: can you paste definition for `BigFileUploadRequest`? is it streaming?

Comment: This is not a "streaming" request.  `BigFileUploadRequest` is an arbitrary POCO used to get the form data.  It is irrelevant,

Comment: while setting max messages size possible, it is always suggested to streaming upload large files(objects, bytes) and consider the possibility of continue after networking interrupting.

Comment: @LeiYang Without going on to a diatribe, you're saying "you're doing it wrong".  You answer doesn't take in to account the context of it being an internal, local management API; nor the the use of middleware (ServiceStack);  nor the fact that I have post data.  You're saying I need to use my limited time to rewrite the application if I want to upload a ... say... 35MiB file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: i cannot imagin a so user with so many scores cannot use search, there are many similiar questions and answers out there. i've seen at least 3 kind of solutions, but you say you only tried one or two.

Comment: @LeiYang Perhaps this is better in discussion, but I *did* in fact try 2 of the 3 solutions in the solution you linked.  In fact, in the question itself I showed attempts to use both `RequestSizeLimit` (I'm not using AspNetMVC) and `IHttpMaxSizeRequestBodySizeFeature` based options (which I stated mysteriously didn't work).  The last required hosting-specific solutions (Kestrel or HttpSys) which I don't feel comfortable using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to the `ConfigureServices` method of my StartUp seems to work.  Ideally I'd have a per-endpoint setting, but this is sufficient for now.

```cs
// Set to allow 300MiB files for device software uploads
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 300 * 1024 * 1024;
});
```