# After upgrading to Firefox 100 version, normal file upload control stop working for medium/larger files uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, firefox, iis, file-upload

We have a normal file upload control in our ASP.NET Core 2.2 website. File control was working fine for smaller, medium and larger files. But after upgrading Firefox version to 100, it stopped working for all users. If file size is less than 250 kb then it works sometimes.

**For older Firefox versions and other web browsers (Chrome, Edge) it is still working fine.**

**No error coming at UI/web console:**

**Error at Server side as below:**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer|Connection ID "18014398536862412939", Request ID "8000308c-0006-fa00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: The client has disconnected ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified network name is no longer available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070040)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IO.AsyncIOOperation.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadBody()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadAsync(Memory`1 memory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.EnsureBufferedAsync(Int32 minCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
   at DevExpress.AspNetCore.Bootstrap.Internal.AspNetCoreUploadContext.GetRequestFormValue(String key)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core) answer your question?

Comment: thank you @NightOwl888. I will try this out but our problem is related Firefox version 100 only. File uploading is working fine in all other browsers without any size limit.

Comment: Check if the below helps
https://www.askvg.com/fix-firefox-100-or-later-versions-having-issues-with-some-websites/

Comment: Thank you @PranJoseph, I had already tried this before but it is not working. Thank you for your kind help. And even if it could work, we can't tell each client users to changes their version like this.