# Error in reading large models using angular and dot net core

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, .net-core

I am taking the revit and json file from user using below

[image]

The `uploadModelsonRevitandForge` function contains following code:

[image]

and sending this to API as shown in the code ,

The API code as follows

[image]

### Problem

It works fine when both the files are smaller in memory size approx 300mb, but it fails for larger size models, We are getting the 502 bad request error.

Files are not reaching to the backend code and get timeout error for HTTP request

Could anyone please suggest any workaround for this

Tried replacing IForm files with Multipart

Comment: Add your code as text, not a screenshot...

Comment: It might have reached the maximum file size limit. Use the DisableRequestSizeLimit in your action attribute.

Comment: The server may have limits on size of data and the server limits may need to be increased.

Answer (score 0):

It's a server problem. There is a limit, by default, on the maximum size af a file you can upload.
Take a look at [increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

You'll find there a working answer.